# why I see the keyboard when I start a new Intent?

Tags: android

I have a problem with my android app: When I start a new Intend like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyFirstActivity.this, MySecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

android opens the keyboard when I see the `MySecondActivity` and I dont know why.

how to disable this?

EDIT: this is my layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MySecondActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/foo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextBemerkung"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:hint="@string/bemerkung" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:hint="@string/foo" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/foo2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/foo"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewFoto2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/foto"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewAnzahl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/anzahl" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/foo3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/foo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/foo4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/foo" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/foo6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:hint="@string/foo" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/foo7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:hint="@string/foo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/foo8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/foo" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/foo9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="@string/foo" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show us the layout. Do you have an input that gets the focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any Edit-text / focusable input that is getting focussed then the keyboard will open. Use the following in your layout xml for that view :

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

So it will be like :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextBemerkung"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:hint="@string/bemerkung"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: You could accept it as answer, if it works for you and also so that it is helpful for others who view this post. :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated, this is most likely due to your `EditText` having focus when the `Activity` starts so you can give focus to a different `View` or you can add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden
```

to your `<activity>` tag in your `manifest`. This will hide the keyboard until you click in the `EditText`

At the bottom of [these Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) are some other helpful attributes when dealing with the keyboard